# Set element size proportionally to screen size in css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am building a react application that is meant to be a website, but primarily to be used on smartphones, tablets and other devices.
in order to ensure nice layout I set the `body` size to:

```
 width: 360px;
height: 800px;
```

this looks nice on my laptop browser and on some smartphones, but what I really want to do is to set the size proportionally to the screen size, to allow iPads to have a bigger size.
basically I want the height to be proportional to the screen size, and the width to be proportional to the height.

looking for code like:

```
height: screen.size() % 800
width: height *(360/800)
```

Thanks in advance

Also,
what is best to use vh, vw, px, % when I want my site to be responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to the viewport width (vw) and viewport height (vh) sizing in css. If you set:

```
height: 80vw; /* that is, 80% of the screen width */
width: 80vw; /* width is also 80% of the screen width */
```

...then you don't have to make extra calculations in your code. With these css settings you get a square that has edges 80% width of the viewport, eg. 288×288px if the screen is 360px wide).

Comment: This worked, 
I changed it to: width: 45vh; height: 100vh; 
Thank you!